# Callback sendo executada no momento que carrega a página

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo alguns teste para aprender mais sobre `callback` no javascript e encontrei a seguinte dificuldade:

```js
function nome_existe(element) {
  console.log(element.id);
}
window.onload = function() {
  Array.from(document.getElementById("form_id")).forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.addEventListener("blur", nome_existe(element));
  });
};
```

```html
<form id="form_id" method="POST" action="/cloud/criar-conta.php" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="input_nome" id="input_nome" placeholder="Insira um nome" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_email" id="input_email" placeholder="" value="Insira um email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_email_c" id="input_email_c" placeholder="" value="Confirme seu email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_tel" id="input_tel" placeholder="" value="(DDD) - _____ - ____" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="input_senha" id="input_senha" placeholder="Digite uma senha" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="input_senha_c" id="input_senha_c" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="input_check" id="input_check" onblur="valida_check()" />
  <p id="termo_cad">Concordo com os Termos de Serviçes e Política de Privacidade</p>
  <input type="submit" name="sub_btn" id="sub_btn" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

O trecho coloca os elementos de um `form` em um `array` e teoricamente (na minha mente) deveria atribuir um `listner`ao campo que recebesse o evento `blur` e depois logar o `id` do elemento no console.

A dificuldade é: Por que ao correr o evento `onload`, é logado no console os `ids` de todos os elementos, mesmo sem ocorrer o evento `blur`?

Comment: Mostre o que está ocorrendo, eu imagino que seja o normal, afinal está adicionando todos eles, a chamada é outra coisa.

Comment: Isso ocorre em todos os navegadores?

Comment: O que está ocorrendo é: `console.log(element.id);`. Tenho um `form` com 8 elementos do tipo `text`. Então linha após linha no console é mostrado o id do campo. Entretanto eu gostaria que isso só ocorresse no campo onde houver o `blur`.

Comment: @Renan sim para Chrome e  FF.

Comment: É bem a critério do desenvolvedor mesmo @MagicHat, a forma que estava não estava errada. Eu só editei porque a visualmente a linha onde tem o `Array` estava junto com a chaves que abre a função e tava confundido um pouco a análise. Eu só usei o identador automático (Organizar) do snippet :p

Comment: Um blz... Pra falar a verdade eu não sei como seis consegue, indentar cada linguagem num estilo, já abri mão faço tudo igual... Mai dexa assim mesmo..Vlw man...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se a função não for anônima ela será invocada no registro do evento. No seu caso, você pode invocar `nome_existe` dentro de uma função anônima no *callback* de `blur`:

```js
function nome_existe(element) {
  console.log(element.id);
}
window.onload = function() {
  Array.from(document.getElementById("form_id")).forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.addEventListener("blur", function() {
      nome_existe(element);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<form id="form_id" method="POST" action="/cloud/criar-conta.php" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="input_nome" id="input_nome" placeholder="Insira um nome" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_email" id="input_email" placeholder="" value="Insira um email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_email_c" id="input_email_c" placeholder="" value="Confirme seu email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_tel" id="input_tel" placeholder="" value="(DDD) - _____ - ____" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="input_senha" id="input_senha" placeholder="Digite uma senha" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="input_senha_c" id="input_senha_c" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="input_check" id="input_check" onblur="valida_check()" />
  <p id="termo_cad">Concordo com os Termos de Serviçes e Política de Privacidade</p>
  <input type="submit" name="sub_btn" id="sub_btn" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

### Chamando uma função declarada fora do *callback*:

Uma implementação muito comum é invocar uma função fora sem argumentos onde a função terá o escopo de quem invocou:

```js
function nome_existe() {
  console.log(this.id);
}
window.onload = function() {
  Array.from(document.getElementById("form_id")).forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.addEventListener("blur", nome_existe);
  });
}
```

```html
<form id="form_id" method="POST" action="/cloud/criar-conta.php" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="input_nome" id="input_nome" placeholder="Insira um nome" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_email" id="input_email" placeholder="" value="Insira um email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_email_c" id="input_email_c" placeholder="" value="Confirme seu email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_tel" id="input_tel" placeholder="" value="(DDD) - _____ - ____" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="input_senha" id="input_senha" placeholder="Digite uma senha" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="input_senha_c" id="input_senha_c" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="input_check" id="input_check" onblur="valida_check()" />
  <p id="termo_cad">Concordo com os Termos de Serviçes e Política de Privacidade</p>
  <input type="submit" name="sub_btn" id="sub_btn" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

### Chamando uma função declarada fora do callback com argumentos

Caso necessário usar argumentos na função declarada, um jeito seria fazer *bind*:

```js
function nome_existe(arg) {
  console.log(this.id, arg);
}
window.onload = function() {
  Array.from(document.getElementById("form_id")).forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.addEventListener("blur", nome_existe.bind(element, 'Index: ' + index));
  });
}
```

```html
<form id="form_id" method="POST" action="/cloud/criar-conta.php" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="input_nome" id="input_nome" placeholder="Insira um nome" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_email" id="input_email" placeholder="" value="Insira um email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_email_c" id="input_email_c" placeholder="" value="Confirme seu email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_tel" id="input_tel" placeholder="" value="(DDD) - _____ - ____" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="input_senha" id="input_senha" placeholder="Digite uma senha" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="input_senha_c" id="input_senha_c" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="input_check" id="input_check" onblur="valida_check()" />
  <p id="termo_cad">Concordo com os Termos de Serviçes e Política de Privacidade</p>
  <input type="submit" name="sub_btn" id="sub_btn" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: Massa, me diz uma coisa eu obrigatoriamente preciso da anonima, tem como eu passar só a função?

Comment: Não obrigatóriamente @MagicHat. Você pode nomear a função, desde que ela não tenha sido declarada fora do *callback*. Se quiser que a função fique desacoplada, deve chamá-la sem invocação passando o contexto. Atualizei a resposta =]

Comment: Show...bacana, vlw man

Comment: Se não houver parâmetros tu pode apenas colocar o nome da função sem os parênteses e ela não executará no momento da declaração. Porém se ela tiver parâmetros ai acredito que realmente não tenha como sem usar a anônima, a não ser que seja possível usando aquelas paradas do `.call` mas não sei te afirmar se tem como.

Comment: Sim @PauloRoberto, com `bind`.

Answer (score 4):

Se queres guardar uma referência do elemento que está a ser iterado podes usar `.bind()` que vai criar uma função, passando como primeiro argumento o elemento.

Mas na verdade não precisas mais do que passar a tua função `nome_existe` e usar o `this` dentro dela. O `this` é sempre o elemento que tem o `.addEventListener`.

Exemplo:

```js
function nome_existe(event) {
  console.log(this.id, event.type);
}
window.onload = function() {
  Array.from(document.getElementById("form_id")).forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.addEventListener("blur", nome_existe);
  });
};

function valida_check(){

}
```

```html
<form id="form_id" method="POST" action="/cloud/criar-conta.php" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="input_nome" id="input_nome" placeholder="Insira um nome" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_email" id="input_email" placeholder="" value="Insira um email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_email_c" id="input_email_c" placeholder="" value="Confirme seu email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_tel" id="input_tel" placeholder="" value="(DDD) - _____ - ____" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="input_senha" id="input_senha" placeholder="Digite uma senha" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="input_senha_c" id="input_senha_c" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="input_check" id="input_check" onblur="valida_check()" />
  <p id="termo_cad">Concordo com os Termos de Serviçes e Política de Privacidade</p>
  <input type="submit" name="sub_btn" id="sub_btn" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As funções *callbacks* que lidam com os eventos no JavaScript recebem como parâmetro o objeto que descreve o respectivo evento. O objeto do evento possui o atributo `target` que representa o elemento alvo deste evento. Neste caso, o parâmetro da função `nome_existe` será o evento `blur` e o atributo `target` deste objeto será o campo do formulário. Desta forma, você poderá acessar o `id` do campo com `evento.target.id`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function nome_existe(evento) {
  console.log(evento.target.id);
}

window.onload = function () {

  for (let element of document.getElementById("form_id")) {
    element.addEventListener("blur", nome_existe);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form id="form_id" method="POST" action="/cloud/criar-conta.php" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="input_nome" id="input_nome" placeholder="Insira um nome" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_email" id="input_email" placeholder="" value="Insira um email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_email_c" id="input_email_c" placeholder="" value="Confirme seu email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input_tel" id="input_tel" placeholder="" value="(DDD) - _____ - ____" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="input_senha" id="input_senha" placeholder="Digite uma senha" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="input_senha_c" id="input_senha_c" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="input_check" id="input_check" onblur="valida_check()" />
  <p id="termo_cad">Concordo com os Termos de Serviçes e Política de Privacidade</p>
  <input type="submit" name="sub_btn" id="sub_btn" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

A partir do ECMAScript 2015 é possível utilizar a notação `for ... of` como utilizei acima. A lógica sobre *callback*, que é o contexto da pergunta, é exatamente a mesma. Pode ser aplicada junto com o `Array.forEach` da mesma forma. Utilizei-a como forma de completar as outras respostas, apresentando uma forma distinta.

Comment: `Em construção... publiquei sem querer ;p` kkkkkkk primeira vez que vejo essa, criativo